# Let $G$ be a finite group and $M$ be a maximal subgroup of $G$. If $G = Z(G)M$, then $M$ is normal in $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, direct-product, maximal-subgroup

I need to prove that if $G$ is a group, $M$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$ and $Z(G) \nsubseteq M$,then $M \unlhd G$. Is true that $G = Z(G)M$, right? Is this enough?

Comment: You don't need $M$ to be maximal, and you don't need to assume $Z(G)$ is not contained in $M$. Any subgroup $H$ such that $Z(G)H=G$ is said to be "cocentral". It is an easy exercise to show that any cocentral subgroup must be normal: just take an element of $h$, and conjugate by an arbitrary element of $G$ to show the result lies in $H$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin But, my understanding of the question was that we are told that $M$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$ and that $Z(G) \not\subseteq M$. From this we can deduce that  $G =Z(G)M$ - it was not given as an assumption.

Comment: @DerekHolt:  I confess I was going by the subject line, rather than the body. So the problem here is that we have two different problems stated, one in the subject line, one in the body. In the subject line, $Z(G)M=G$ is the premise...

Comment: You have a different problem in the subject line than in the body. Please clarify which problem you are actually asking.

Comment: By hipotesis I have that $M$ is maximal in $G$ and $Z(G) \nsubseteq M$, and I want to show that $M$ is normal in $G$. I conclue that $G = Z(G)M$, because if $Z(G) \nsubseteq M$, then $Z(G) \nsubseteq \Phi(G)$ thus exist $M$ maximal wich $MZ(G) = G$. From what you tell me, that's enough. Thanks!

Comment: It's rather a long way around to show $G=Z(G)M$! Clearly, $Z(G)M=MZ(G)$, so it is a subgroup. It contains $Z(G)$ and $M$; hence from $Z(G)\not\subseteq M$, you know that $M\lt Z(G)M\leq G$, hence $Z(G)M=G$ by maximality.